# $q.reject and $state.resolve not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have this function:

```
// Gets our sport
get: function (slug, kit) {

    // If we have no slug, exit the function
    if (!slug)
        return $q.reject('No slug supplied.');

    // Try to get our sport
    return moltin.categories.get(slug).then(function (response) {

        // If we have a kit
        if (kit) {

            // Assign our sport to our kit
            kit.team.sport = response.slug;
        }

        // Return our response
        return response;
    });
}
```

As you can see I am using **$q.reject()** if my required parameter is not set.
The problem is, in a **$state** resolve method, if I invoke the function like this:

```
resolve: {

    sport: ['$stateParams', 'kit', 'SimpleDesignerSharedSportService', function ($stateParmas, kit, sharedSport) {

        // Get our slug
        var slug = $stateParmas.sport || kit.team.sport;

        // Get our sport
        return sharedSport.get(slug, kit);
    }]
}
```

my view will not be shown (it is just blank). But if I change my resolve to this:

```
resolve: {

    sport: ['$stateParams', 'kit', 'SimpleDesignerSharedSportService', function ($stateParmas, kit, sharedSport) {

        // Get our slug
        var slug = $stateParmas.sport || kit.team.sport;

        // Get our sport
        return sharedSport.get(slug, kit).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        }, function (error) {
            return null;
        });
    }],

    pageTitle: ['PageHead', function (service) {
        service.setTitle('Kudos Sports - Create your kit');
    }]
}
```

it works. I don't want to have to specify a success and fail method. Is there anyway I can get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolves expect a promise so that it can resolve it before loading the page. There are a few issues in your code that I will help you identify and solve, however I strongly suggest you take [this short course on Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898) and brush up on your understanding of promises.

Firstly, we need to refactor your get method to return a promise once your data is resolved.

```
// Gets our sport
get: function (slug, kit) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  // If we have no slug, exit the function
  if (!slug)
    deferred.reject('No slug supplied.');

  // Try to get our sport
  moltin.categories.get(slug).then(function (response) {

    // If we have a kit
    if (kit) {

        // Assign our sport to our kit
        kit.team.sport = response.slug;
    }

    // Return our response
    deferred.resolve(response);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

As you can see, you can't just return the data in the promise. You have to create another promise and return that once there is data.

The next step is to consume this function within a resolve. You seems to have used `$stateParmas` instead of `$stateParams` so we correct that as well. Also, it is bad practice to name your services differently in different places. Keeping consistent with naming conventions makes debugging much easier.

```
resolve: {

  sport: ['$stateParams', 'kit', 'SimpleDesignerSharedSportService', function ($stateParams, kit, SimpleDesignerSharedSportService) {

    // Get our slug
    var slug = $stateParams.sport || kit.team.sport;

    // Get our sport
    return SimpleDesignerSharedSportService.get(slug, kit);
  }]
}
```

Now the get method returns a promise that only resolves once there is a response from fetching the categories and you once again have control of the data flow.